# Fluttes doesn't update Image state

Tags: image, file, flutter, mobile, dart

I've trying to pick an image from gallery and put inside a container, but if I pick one and then pick another one, the image inside container still being the first one.

I've tried to delete the image first, but it still in the container. By Android Studio and with some break points I've realized that it deletes and copy the new image, but doesn't call the build method to refresh the image widget.

**Code to pick the image:**

```
pickImage() async {
    final String path = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;       

    final bool fileExists = await File.fromUri(Uri(path: '$path/logo.png')).exists();

    if(fileExists)
       await File('$path/logo.png').delete();

    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    imageCache.clear();

    if(image == null)
      return;        

    File newImage = await image.copy('$path/logo.png');
    new FileImage(File('$path/logo.png')).evict();

    setState(() {
       _image = newImage;
       imagePath = newImage.path;
    });
}
```

**Layout structure**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,    
    appBar: AppBar(    
      title: Text(
          'Profile',
          style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Brandon',
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff365951),
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Color(0xffeec1b2)),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ), 
    ),
    body: new IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,                
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,           
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    height: 150,
                    width: 150,
                    child: Center(
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: pickImage,
                        child: (imagePath == '') ? Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget> [
                            Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                            Text(
                              'PICTURE', 
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,                                      
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontFamily: 'Brandon'
                              )
                            )
                          ]
                        ) : ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          child: new Image.file(new File(imagePath)),
                        )
                      ),
                    ),                    
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(                  
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Color(0xff365951),                                      
                    ),
                  ),     
                ),
              ]
            )
          )
        )
      )
  );
}
```

Comment: If I had to guess, the widget is probably caching the image data based on the file path. Why are you doing this complicated song and dance of copying and deleting images in the first place? Why not just pass the path to the original image?

Comment: I've to store the image inside application's folder, so I copy it from gallery to application's folder

Comment: But why though? Why not load the image into memory and use that?

Comment: So, I can load the image from gallery, show it up and after store at application's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
await image.copy(path).then((Value) {setState(() {});});
```